# Inherit Properties of TextField Widget to create a custom styled TextField Widget in Flutter

Tags: reactjs, flutter, widget

Does anyone have an idea on how you can kind of create **reusable Styled Widgets**?
For example, I want to create a make a widget that is a TextField with some specific styles applied. It should still have all the functionality of a normal TextField.

I tried extending **TextField** but this doesn't work.

What does work is returning a TextField and applying all the styles but then I have no idea on how to get **onChanged**, **onSaved** etc on the StyledWidget.

Do I really need to code all the properties manually and then place them on the TextField in the return method of the styled widget? Or is there something like **...props** as in React & React Native?

Didn't find anything online regarding this.

Comment: once you style a widget> copy the stylized widget >  create new statefulwidget > return the stylized widget by pasting it, that simple buddy , way to go

Comment: @iamyadunandan The problem with this is if I do this I'm not able to pass arguments to the Styled Widget. For example if I make a styled textfield, I cant add labelText etc.

Comment: pass arguments to the widgets constructor, after that you can access them using widget variable in the state of the object

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!
So basically I would need to pass all the possible arguments of textfield to the constructor of my custom widget? 

Is there no faster way or a more DRY way?

Answer (score 0):

psuedo code

```
AStatefulWidget{
String name;
 AStatefulWidget({this.name}){
  
 }
}

AStatefulWidgetState{
 build(){
  return Text(widget.name);
 }
}
```

you can use the widget like this while passing the name parameter

```
child: AStatefulWidget(name : 'yadunandan'),
```